# how to make web request and get the response using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i am trying  to make a web service from WSDL so i have added the service reference , the aacheck takes 3 parameters username,password and the result
i cant handle the third parameter it keep display

> argument 3 must be passed with ref keyword

how to fix this ?
the code:

```
ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient req = new ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient();           
 req.aaCheck(username.Text, password.Text,third parameter);
```

I have tried to replace the third parameter with lable.Text did not work also .tostring(); and still not work what should i replace with the third parameter

[image: Error message]

Comment: Pleas post code as text, not as image.

Comment: ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient req = new ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient();

        req.aaCheck(username.Text, password.Text,third parameter);

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more information

Comment: Done i have edit it .

Comment: ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient req = new ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient(); req.aaCheck(username.Text, password.Text, ref thirdParameter); - Note the 'ref' keyword before the third parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your web service seems to expect a `ref string` as third parameter. Guessing from the parameter name probably to return some result.
The following will work:

```
string resultDesc = "";
req.aaCheck(username.Text, password.Text, ref resultDesc);
label.Text = resultDesc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as the error message says - pass the value in with the 'ref' keyword in front of it.

```
var someResult = String.Empty;

ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient req = new ServiceReference1.nwebserviceClient(); 
req.aaCheck(username.Text, password.Text, ref someReult);
```

Then you can do what you want with `someResult`.